# Gigapixel images Android app

Tags: android, image, out-of-memory

I'm working on an Android App to show images. One of the requisites is show gigapixel images.

I found problems with memory showing normal images (>=1Mb) but i think that i have solved it. 
For gigapixel images, wich is the best way to manage this files (>=15Mb) and prevent OutOfMemory errors?
Anybody had worked with this types of images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anytime ive ever seen anything like this done (bearing in mind this is more when Ive seen super sized textures being applied in rendering engines) the images are brought in in tiles, much like the way google maps brings things in.

Based on the zoom level different images (mipmaps) are used, each having a different level of detail, and you only load the tiles necessary.  This way (depending on what you need from the application) you can get away with loading small images but keeping a very high level of detail when zoomed in.

Comment: adding on to that, you can also just use the very large image and and use sub-sampling to render the image at a lower quality when needed. Then you don't need duplicate images at different qualities. (You essentially create the lower quality images on the fly)

Answer (score 1):

Android has memory limitations for App, normally about 48/64MB.
I'm the author of PPV360HD, a Gigapixel Pano Viewer for Android. I've used C++, the native layer doesn't have this constraints.